# nginx proxy GET to one server, GET & everything else on another one

Tags: nginx

I have a new version of our app and it needs to be tested before placed everywhere in production.

There is one main machine that currently receives all requests and forwards them to an Apache using proxy_pass. I want to add another server, and forward only some GET requests to it.

Can nginx be configured to do that?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what requests need to go to what server?  Is it a specific path that will have the GET requests in question, or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to setup a second upstream in your configuration and then use something to send specific requests there.  Like:

```
upstream old_upstream {
    1.2.3.4:8080;
}
upstream new_upstream {
    5.6.7.8:8080;
}
set $upstream old_upstream;
if ( somecondition where you want to use the new server ) {
  set $upstream new_upstream;
}
location / {
  proxy_pass http://$upstream;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply go without upstreams and use the short version.

```
location / {
  if (somecondition for new server ) {
    proxy_pass http://5.6.7.8:8080;
    break;
  }

  proxy_pass http://1.2.3.4:8080;
}
```

please +1 if it helped :) thanks